# Is it possible to merge these two methods in one, possibly using.. polymorphism?

Tags: java, android

In my android application I have ItemCategory POJO and ItemSubcategory POJO that both extend Category POJO holding some common characteristics.

I have a custom Load Spinner method that I pass an ArrayList of Objects to, and it loads them into a spinner (the Android name for drop-down/select)

I tried passing an ArrayList to a single method loadCategoriesIntoSpinner( that accepts an ArrayList as a parameter) and I expected it to sort out that what Im passing is an ArrayList but it didnt.

```
public static void loadCategoriesIntoSpinner(Context context, ArrayList<ItemCategory> array, Spinner spinner) {

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory>(context,
            R.drawable.simple_spinner_item, array);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

public static void loadSubcategoriesIntoSpinner(Context context, ArrayList<ItemSubcategory> array, Spinner spinner) {

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<ItemSubcategory> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemSubcategory>(context,
            R.drawable.simple_spinner_item, array);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Here are the Category objects:

Main class Category:

```
abstract public class Category {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

} // End of Class
```

inheriting class ItemCategory

```
public class ItemCategory extends Category {

    private String logo;

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

}  // End of Class
```

inheriting class ItemSubcategory:

```
public class ItemSubcategory extends Category {

    private int parentID;

    public void setParentID(int parentID) {
        this.parentID = parentID;
    }

    public int getParentID() {
        return parentID;
    }

}  // End of Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void <T extends Category> loadCategoriesIntoSpinner(Context context, List<T> array, Spinner spinner) {
    ArrayAdapter<T> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(context, R.drawable.simple_spinner_item, array);
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void loadSubcategoriesIntoSpinner(Context context, List<? extends Category> array, Spinner spinner)
```

or also

```
public static void loadSubcategoriesIntoSpinner(Context context, List<Category> array, Spinner spinner)
```

if you create your list as `List<Category>`.

I suggest you use the interface `List` instead of a specific implementation like `ArrayList`. This way you can change the implementation (to `LinkedList` for example) without having to modify your code.

Comment: what feature am I going to have to give up on, if not using ArrayList instead of List?

Comment: Using the List interface means you can change your implementation details (i.e. use a different List implementation) without changing any of your other code. It's best practice to do it that way.

Comment: so no matter what list I have (linkedList, arrayList) I can always pass it to a method that accepts a List

Comment: That's right. Any class that implements List interface.